# Check records from same table with unmatched values in multiple rows based on date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to select the unmatched combination from the same table:

Table 1

[image]

So as per the above table, #Id combination (#3,#4,#5) is missing for date 15-Sep-2018 and #Id combination (#8,#9,#10) is completely different for 15-Sep-2018 as compared to 14-Sep-2018.

So I want to select such IDs [ #Id combination (#8,#9,#10) ] and print it

How do I find this through query?

Comment: That's a difficult question to understand. Could you provide the exact output you expect (preferably in table form) and we can work from there?

Answer (score 0):

When you say "Combination #8" you actually just mean Server 3 + License 1? Something like this?

```
declare @daycount int
select @daycount = count(distinct [date]) from table1

select ServerID, LicenseID
from table1
group by ServerID, LicenseID
having count(*) != @daycount
```